# Create two version for a package

Tags: npm, repository, npm-package

Is it possible provide two version of a same package npm ?

I have a git repository with :

```
MyRepo
|- library
|- FolderToHide
|- package.json
|- .npmignore
```

File package.json is containing :

```
{
   "name": "myRepo",
   "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "https://somewhere"
   },
   ...
}
```

How can I configure my package to create a version with `FolderToHide` and another without ?

I want to have something like this :

```
MyRepo2
|- node_modules
  |- myRepo
    |- library

MyRepo3
|- node_modules
  |- myRepo
    |- library
    |- FolderToHide
```

MyRepo3 can be used as debug repository, maybe is it possible to create a debug version for a package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be single npm package, e.g. `my-package` (not two separate packages `my-package` and `my-package-with-hidden-folder`) you can use [dist-tags](https://docs.npmjs.com/adding-dist-tags-to-packages) for this.

1. When you made changes to your package which you want to publish, add `FolderToHide` to your `.npmignore`.
2. Add `-limited` to version of your package in `package.json` (so it looks like `2.1.0-limited`) and run `npm publish --tag limited` (you can replace `limited` with any name you want). This will publish version of package without `FolderToHide` with tag `limited`.
3. Remove `FolderToHide` from `.npmignore`
4. Change `-limited` in `package.json` to `-full` and run `npm publish --tag full` (again, `full` can be any name you wish). This will publish new version of package with `FolderToHide` included.

Then, when you want to install your package in another project you run either `npm install my-package@limited` or `npm install my-package@full`.

Alternatively, you can decide to have one of versions as default option. In this case you should omit dist-tag for it. So instead of `npm publish --tag full` you just run `npm publish`. This will (implicitly) assign tag `latest` to published version. And when you install package without specifying tag (`npm install my-package`), npm will use package with `latest` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to publish two different packages to npm (or similar), but do not want 2 "repositories"?

Ok, first, create a node-script in the root of your package that you for example call "publish.js".

In that script you put something like this (pseudo code):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

let packageJSON = fs.readFileSync("path to package.json");

// For the first package,without the hiddenfolder:
packageJSON.files = ["library", "package.json", "any  other file you want to include in the package"];

fs.writeFileSync("path to the project package.json", JSON.stringify(packageJSON, null, 2), 'utf-8');

// then run publish (version first if pref)

const publish = spawn('npm', ['publish']);

publish.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

publish.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

// For the second package,with the hiddenfolder:
packageJSON = fs.readFileSync("path to package.json");
packageJSON.files = ["library", "hiddenFolder","package.json", "any  other file you want to include in the package"];

fs.writeFileSync("path to the project package.json", JSON.stringify(packageJSON, null, 2), 'utf-8');


// then run publish (version first if pref)

const publish = spawn('npm', ['publish']);

publish.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

publish.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});
```

Then add a script tag in your `package.json`:

```json
{
  …
  "scripts": {
    …
    "release": "node ./publish.js",
    …
  }
  …
}
```

And so, every time you want to release, just run `npm run release`. `npm pack` will only pack the contents of what is in the `files` array. Click [here for full documentation regarding `files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#files)

**NOTE** This is just unproven pseudo code, YMMV.

*One other option is to copy to a temp directory (hidden by both `.npmignore` and `.gitignore` including a modified `package.json` that contains `files` that you want to release, and run `npm publish` from that directory.*